# Java - How to add list of maps to 2D object array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, hashmap

I am building the below code to read an excel file and get a list of hashmaps into a 2 dimensional object array:

```
public static Object[][] getTableAsMapObject(String xlFileName, String xlSheetName) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> dataMap = null;
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Object[][] tabArray = null;

    String masterDataFilePath = "./data/MasterData.xlsx";
    try {
        FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream("./data/" + xlFileName + ".xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook excelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        XSSFSheet excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheet(xlSheetName);
        row = excelWSheet.getRow(0);
        int totalCols = row.getLastCellNum();
        totalCols--;
        int startRow = 1;
        int startCol = 1;
        int ci, cj;
        int totalRows = excelWSheet.getLastRowNum();
        int activeRows = 0;
        ci = 0;
        for (int i = startRow; i <= totalRows; i++, ci++) {
            if (getCellData(excelWSheet, i, 0).trim().toUpperCase().equals("YES")
                    || getCellData(excelWSheet, i, 0).trim().toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
                activeRows++;
            }
        }

        tabArray = new Object[activeRows][0];
        ci = 0;
        for (int i = startRow; i <= totalRows; i++) {// , ci++) {
            cj = 0;
            if (getCellData(excelWSheet, i, 0).trim().toUpperCase().equals("YES")
                    || getCellData(excelWSheet, i, 0).trim().toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
                dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int j = startCol; j <= totalCols; j++) {

                    String colName = getCellData(excelWSheet, 0, j);
                    if (colName.contains("_")) {
                        String[] bits = colName.split("_");
                        String lastOne = bits[bits.length-1];
                        if (lastOne.equalsIgnoreCase("key")) {
                            dataMap = getMasterDataSet(masterDataFilePath, bits[0], getCellData(excelWSheet, i, j), dataMap);
                        }
                    } else { dataMap.put(colName, getCellData(excelWSheet, i, j)); }
                    cj++;
                }
                listOfMaps.add(dataMap);
                **tabArray = new Object[][] { {dataMap} }; //<== Here I want all the maps in listOfMaps to be added to tabArray**
                dataMap = null;
                ci++;
            }
        }
        excelWBook.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (tabArray);
}
```

I am unable to get the whole list of maps into object array, instead I am able to get only one map. Eventually this should do something like:

```
tabArray = new Object[][] { {dataMap1}, {dataMap2}, ... };
```

Comment: `listOfMaps.toArray()`???

Comment: Clean code? Single abstraction layer? Single responsibility principle? Just in case you want to improve the quality of your code, you might want to google these terms and see how they not apply to your code ;-)

Comment: You only have a 1D list; A list of maps. You don't have a List of Lists, so I'm not sure how you'd expect to get to a 2D `Object[][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the modified which worked for me:

```
public static Object[][] getTableAsMapObject(String xlFileName, String xlSheetName) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> dataMap = null;
        Object[][] tabArray = null;

        String masterDataFilePath = "./data/MasterData.xlsx";
        try {
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream("./data/" + xlFileName + ".xlsx");
            // Access the required test data sheet
            XSSFWorkbook excelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            XSSFSheet excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheet(xlSheetName);
            row = excelWSheet.getRow(0);
            int totalCols = row.getLastCellNum();
            totalCols--;
            int startRow = 1;
            int startCol = 1;
            int ci;
            int totalRows = excelWSheet.getLastRowNum();
            int activeRows = 0;
            ci = 0;
            for (int i = startRow; i <= totalRows; i++, ci++) {
                if (getCellData(excelWSheet, i, 0).trim().toUpperCase().equals("YES")
                        || getCellData(excelWSheet, i, 0).trim().toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
                    activeRows++;
                }
            }
            tabArray = new Object[activeRows][1]; //***<<< Changing 0 to 1 did the trick
            ci = 0;
            for (int i = startRow; i <= totalRows; i++) {
                if (getCellData(excelWSheet, i, 0).trim().toUpperCase().equals("YES")
                        || getCellData(excelWSheet, i, 0).trim().toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
                    dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    for (int j = startCol; j <= totalCols; j++) {

                        String colName = getCellData(excelWSheet, 0, j);
                        if (colName.contains("_")) {
                            String[] bits = colName.split("_");
                            String lastOne = bits[bits.length-1];
                            if (lastOne.equalsIgnoreCase("key")) {
                                dataMap = getMasterDataSet(masterDataFilePath, bits[0], getCellData(excelWSheet, i, j), dataMap);
                            }
                        } else { dataMap.put(colName, getCellData(excelWSheet, i, j)); }
                    }
                    tabArray[ci][0] = dataMap;
                    dataMap = null;
                    ci++;
                }
            }
            excelWBook.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (tabArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just decompose your `map` and enter it in your `Object[][]`

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Object[][] tabArray = new Object[2][];
tabArray[0] = map.keySet().toArray();
tabArray[1] = map.values().toArray();
```

### Note from the JavaDoc for `keySet()` and `values()`

> No synchronization is performed, so there is a slight chance that
>   multiple calls to this method will not all return the same set.